# Prepare of prepared statement failing with a select query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following prepared statement that is failing in the prepared part. The database table is correct, as are the table columns. I have a similar prepared statement above this that works just fine. Does anyone see what is wrong in my prepare?

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");

if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {

    die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));

}

if(!$stmt2->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {

    die('Select forum posts bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));

}

if(!$stmt2->execute()) {

    die('Select forum posts execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));

}
```

**Updated:**

Error message - Select forum posts prepare() failed:

Full code as requested:

Using Chris Brand's answer - it gets me to the bind param and stops there...

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

//Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum topics
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND id=? LIMIT 1");
if (!$stmt || $con->error ) {
    die('Select topics prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {
    die('Select topics bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die('Select topics execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }

    foreach($stmt as $row) {

        //Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum posts
        if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?")) {
        //var_dump($stmt2);
        if (!$stmt2) {
            die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
        }
        } else {
        var_dump($con->error);
        }
        if(!$stmt2->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {
            die('Select forum posts bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
        if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
            die('Select forum posts execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
        //while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt2)){
        foreach($stmt2 as $row2) {  
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
            by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
}
```

Using Abdulla's answer:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

//Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum topics
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND id=? LIMIT 1");
if (!$stmt || $con->error ) {
    die('Select topics prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {
    die('Select topics bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die('Select topics execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }

    foreach($stmt as $row) {

            //Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum posts
        $stmt2 = $mysqli::prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE category_id='value' AND topic_id='value'");
        //var_dump($stmt2);
        //if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
            //die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    //  }
        //var_dump($con->error);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2,"i", $cid, $tid)) //i means intiger
        {
            die('Select forum posts bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
        if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2)) {
            die('Select forum posts execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
        //while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt2)){
        foreach($stmt2 as $row2) {  
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
            by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error text. please?

Comment: I added it. It is the error message that is in my die code.

Comment: If anyone needs to see the code above it, just let me know. I don't think that would have any affect, but just in case.

Comment: I saw your old post and it seems it had 2 SELECT queries and the first one working but you have problem in your 2nd SELECT query inside while loop, right?

Comment: Yea, I switched them to foreach loops and it worked fine. Just not getting anything from this query for some reason.

Comment: @Ralph are you using `mysqli` or `PDO` ??

Comment: I tend to mix them sometime, but I am trying to use mysqli

Answer (score 0):

`Prepared Statements` fail for a few reasons:

1) Database is not connected.

2) Query is not correctly being built

```
/* First check the correction */
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    }

/* Secondly try to print out the query after this statement*/

$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");
var_dump($stmt2);
```

My Guess is that `$stmt2` is returning `FALSE`

Comment: `object(mysqli_stmt)#10 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(2) }`

Comment: If the Object is returned ,Then something is wrong in your `if` condition

Comment: Try to debug individually the each `if` condition, first echo `$con->error` and check what you are getting, as suggested in the other answer, use `!empty` coz string in a `if` condition will return `true`

Comment: Echoing `$con->error` doesn't display anything. Aren't I already echoing it anyway in my die statement? What do you mean by the `!empty`

Comment: So in which `if` condition, it is getting exited?

Comment: The prepare one `if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {

    die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));

}`

Comment: Try this `if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error!='' )` and check it out

Comment: It gives me the same prepared failed message

Answer (score 0):

`$con->error` is a string and it may be causing your if statement to evaluate to true.

try something like:

```
$con->free();

if (!$stmt2 || !empty($con->error))
```

or

```
$con->free();

if ($stmt2 = $con->prepare(...))
{
   ...
}
else
{
    var_dump($con->error);
}
```

If your statement object is populated (as indicated in the other answer), it has to be the `$con->error` variable that evaluates to `true`

Update:

You should try and release the previous statement using http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.free.php or http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.close.php.

Comment: The first one did not do anything. The second I entered like this `if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?"));
  //var_dump($stmt2);
  if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
   die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
  }
  var_dump($con->error);` and got this ... `string(0) ""`

Comment: what happens if you remove the `$con->error` from the if statement and just say:

`if (!$stmt2) { var_dump($con->error); }`, does it work then?

Comment: `if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?")) {
  //var_dump($stmt2);
  if (!$stmt2) {
   die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
  }
  } else {
  var_dump($con->error);
  }` ....error `string(0) "" 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in `...I get an error in my bind param now

Comment: is this error by any chance happening after you executed another query first?

Comment: Yes, it is. I posted my full code in my question. I put your answer in it to show..

Comment: Try doing a `$con->free()` before you execute the next statement. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::free()

Comment: You need to call it on the mysqli_result object or the statement object. So you need to release `$stmt->close()` and then after each loop `$stmt2->close()`

Comment: I did it here: `$stmt->close();
 foreach($stmt as $row) {` and it didn't do anything. Wouldn't that harm my foreach loop then?

Comment: You probably only need to do it at the end of the loop for `$stmt2`. Preparing statements into the same variable has known issues of not working and also not populating the error message. Try only closing `$stmt2`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE category_id='value' AND topic_id='value'")
```

//check connection error

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

//Bind parameter values

[read this table](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters)

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2,"i", $cid, $tid)) //i means intiger
{
    die('Select forum posts bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
}
```

[image]

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2)) 
{

    die('Select forum posts execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));

}
```

Comment: I get this error.... `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in `  for this line ... `$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE category_id='value' AND topic_id='value'");`

Comment: problem is with your DB connection

Comment: How? My db is defined and has the correct info. Am I able to use the same variable for my database throughout the page?

Comment: try with `mysqli::prepare()`

Comment: Doing that I get this error... `Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string` ....  `$stmt2 = $mysqli::prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE category_id='value' AND topic_id='value'");`

Comment: Using Chris Brand's last comment I get past the prepare part, but get stuck on the bind part then.

Comment: use Maine. i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: I added in the full code with connection for you answer (at the bottom) and Chris Brand's. Use Maine?